# play framework - SQLite: Enable Foreign Key

Tags: playframework, sqlite, playframework-2.0, foreign-keys

I have a problem when using SQLite with play, SQLite documentation says that [foreign keys are disabled by default, and need to be enabled with each connection](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable).

I am using SQLite with Ebean, in evolution I added this line:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

but It doesn't work, it only works when I open a connection from terminal or SQLite Client and execute that line (`PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;`), I also tried this in the start of the app but with no luck:

```
Ebean.getServer("mom").createSqlUpdate("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;").execute();
```

So, how to enable foreign keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this via an evolution, as the `PRAGMA` is tied to a connection, and not to the database.

Calling the SQL on startup will not work for similar reasons: it will enable the `PRAGMA` only for the connection from the pool you happen to run the query on.

You need to do it for *every* connection that is being used.

According to [the JDBC documentation of Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SettingsJDBC), you can achieve this by configuring the connection pool to execute the `PRAGMA` for every new connection in the `application.conf` file:

```
db.default.initSQL="PRAGMA foreign_keys = true"
```

You can substitute the connection/server name `default` with `mom` or how ever you configured your JDBC connection.

Comment: Hi, for me this is not working. Could you please tell me what im wrong?

My app.conf is 
db {
        sqlite {
            slick.driver = "scala.slick.driver.SQLiteDriver$"
            driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC"
            url = "jdbc:sqlite:./test.db"
           connectionPool = disabled
           initSQL = "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON"
       }
   }

  db.sqlite.initSQL="PRAGMA foreign_keys = true"