# How to enable foreign key validation in SQLite with Slick

Tags: scala, sqlite, slick

I want to enable foreign key validation in SQLite through Slick. I'm using Slick 3.3.0. How do I do this?

Currently I'm connecting to SQLite through a `DatabaseConfig[SQLiteProfile]`, by doing

```
 DatabaseConfig.forConfig(path = configKey, classLoader = getClass.getClassLoader)
```

My config looks like this:

```
{
  "dataSourceClass": "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource",
  "db": {
    "driver": "org.sqlite.JDBC",

    "properties": {
      "foreign_keys": true
    },
    "url": "jdbc:sqlite:/path/to/mydb.sqlite?foreign_keys=on"
  },
  "profile": "slick.jdbc.SQLiteProfile$"
}
```

I've tried adding `?foreign_keys=ON` to the end of my JDBC URL. I've also tried moving the `properties` object out of the `db` object and into the root level.

If I interact with the database directly through JDBC I'm able to get it work:

```
package test

import java.sql.DriverManager

object Main extends App {

  val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:sqlite:/path/to/mydb.sqlite?foreign_keys=on")
  val statement = connection.createStatement()

  // this line throws, because table_with_fk is a table
  // with foreign keys into a different table
  statement.executeUpdate(
    "insert into table_with_fk values (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [play framework - SQLite: Enable Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740910/play-framework-sqlite-enable-foreign-key), SQLite requires you to enable this at the connection level. And that is consistent with your example (you are passing the foreign key option to `getConnection`)

If you're using connection pooling behind the scenes, maybe that's why it doesn't work. Try disabling like in the [database config example](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.3.0/gettingstarted.html#database-configuration).

Alternatively try [running a plain SQL statement](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.3.0/sql.html) with the pragma command `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` before running your query.

Comment: The last code snippet is not what I've tried in my application, its something I made to show what I _did_ get to work, although not in a way that satisfies my need. 

Do you know how I combine a plain SQL statement with a compiled Slick query? I've tried, but can't figure it out.

Comment: @torkel the result of both operations is a `DBIOAction`, which is a monad. You can try chaining together operations using `flatMap` e.g. in a `for` comprehension, or the `>>` opeator, which throws away the result of the first value.

Comment: After fiddling a bit it turned out I wasn't able to compose the query because of a too strict type annotation I had. Your suggestion worked! Thank you.